# how to read from a text file in c++

Tags: c++

My program is a student database which stores student details in a class called "students", with an object called "stud". I created different options through "case statements" to select from to edit the program such as add students details, edit, delete etc. I am attempting to read from a text file. I have searched on ways to implement how to read from text files, however the program does not read from the text file. It does not read at all. I think i am implementing the code the wrong way. The module I am having an issue with is case 7 to read from the text file. tips would be helpful.
The code is below:

```
     #include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring> 
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace std;

class students
    {
        public:

        char name[50];
        char sname[45];

        int idno;
        char cours[40];
        int age;
        int modules;

        void read_data();
        void display();

    }s;

   void students::read_data()
   {
        cout<<"Enter name :";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter Surname : ";
        cin>>sname;
        cout<<"Enter course : ";
        cin>>cours;
        cout<<"Enter age :";
        cin>>age;
        cout<<"Enter modules:";
        cin>>modules;
      }
    void students::display()
    {
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Student ID no : "<<idno<<endl;
        cout<<"Student name is :"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Surname is : "<<sname<<endl;
        cout<<"Student course is :"<<cours<<endl;
        cout<<"Student age is  :"<<age<<endl;
        cout<<"Student modules are:"<<modules<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }

     int main()
     {

       char dow;
       int arr=0;
      do{

        students stud[100];

        cout<<"Press 1 Enter record \n";
        cout<<"Press 2 Display record \n";
        cout<<"\n\t Select option::";

        int idcheck=0;

        int sw;
        cin>>sw;

        switch(sw)
        {

        case 1:
{
        cout<<"\n Enter the data of the student no "<<arr+1<<" is :\n";

                cout<<"\t Enter the Roll No = ";
                int id2;
                int id;

                cin>>id;

                for(int j=0; j<arr; j++)
                {

                    id2=id;
                    if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                    {
                        idcheck=1;
                     }
                 }
                 if(idcheck!=1){
                    stud[arr].idno=id;

                 stud[arr].read_data();

                    arr=arr+1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    cout<<"This Record is Already Entered \n"; 
                 }
               }

                 break;
    case 2:  
   {
    ifstream sfile;
    sfile.open("StudentFile.txt", ios::in);

    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
    cout << setw(12) << "Rollno ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Name   ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Surname    || ";
    cout << setw(12) << "Age  ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Course  ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Module   ||";

    for(int k = 0; k < arr; k++)
    {
        if(stud[k].idno != 'd')
    {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << " ";
            cout << setw(5) << stud[k].idno;                            
            cout << setw(15) << stud[k].name;                           
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].sname;                       
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].age;                         
            cout << setw(12) << stud[k].cours;                       
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].modules;                        
    }
    }
    }
     cout << "\n-------------------------------------------"   << endl;

     sfile.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
     sfile.close();
}

                break;

                default:
                    cout<<"\t Wrong option Selected ";
                    break;
}

    cout<<"\n\n\t Do You Want to Continue Again [Y/N]";
    cin>>dow;

}
while(dow=='y');
return 0;
getch();
}
```

Comment: You probably need this: [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: i just edited the question with s @drescherjm.

Comment: name is a char not a string

Comment: i dont get you. how am i writing a record using a bug

Comment: I think the code you presented is not enough context to understand the problem. I don't understand why you are displaying the records before you read from the file but I am unsure how `stud` got initialized in the first place. Also the display  code probably should be in its own function. Not part of the reading process.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` - this loop is useless, processed once anyway.

Comment: Please include the contents of the `.txt` file and the way you read it.

Comment: i describe the whole program function. i can not post the whole program here. before i display the records there is a part of the case statement that lets me enter student data. once i am done entering then  it displays the student data."stud" is an an object for class "students".@drescherjm

Comment: i just edited it @drescherjm and produced minimal reproducible example

Comment: @bloody so that loop doesn't do anything i suppose.

Comment: @Habitate i just produced it

Comment: I will have to ask you to post your code in a way in which we can copy-paste it and it will compile. As of now, it has quite a couple of syntax and logic errors.

Comment: @Habitate i just fixed the errors and logic errors you can compile it now.